# Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap; at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.getMapOfClassOfAndProviderOfFactoryOf(

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am getting this issue after integrating Dagger 2 to implement dependency injection of ImageDownloader library while running the app.

This is what I did:

In build.gradle. I added these lines:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16"
```

This is my class API in which I wanted to separate dependencies from the activity class:

```
public class ImageDownloaderApi {

    @Inject
    public ImageDownloaderApi(){
    }

    //some other methods here
}
```

In my `MainActivity` I added these lines:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject
    ImageDownloaderApi imageDownloaderApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Then created an `Application` object:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Then registered the `Application` class via the manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

I created a module named `MyApplicationModule` like this:

```
@Module
public abstract class MyApplicationModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MainActivity contributeActivityInjector();
}
```

I created an interface named `MyApplicationComponent`:

```
@Component(modules = { AndroidInjectionModule.class, MyApplicationModule.class})
public interface MyApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
}
```

`MyApplication` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DaggerMyApplicationComponent.create().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

Now after this implementation when I run the app in the emulator, the app crashes with the following logs:

```
  --------- beginning of crash
11-20 14:51:03.201 6745-6745/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.app, PID: 6745
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.getMapOfClassOfAndProviderOfFactoryOf(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:36)
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.getDispatchingAndroidInjectorOfActivity(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:42)
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.injectMyApplication(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:68)
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.inject(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:62)
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.inject(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:16)
    at com.my.app.di.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:19)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.app-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.getMapOfClassOfAndProviderOfFactoryOf(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:36) 
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.getDispatchingAndroidInjectorOfActivity(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:42) 
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.injectMyApplication(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:68) 
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.inject(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:62) 
    at com.my.app.di.DaggerMyApplicationComponent.inject(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:16) 
    at com.my.app.di.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:19) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 18 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

For additional info. I am also getting this warning line before the logs i posted above

```
11-20 14:51:03.172 6745-6745/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Sounds like Guava version mismatch. Can't tell you who's conflicting with who, though. Another possibility is that your "image loader library" if it is a library module, then it should specify Dagger as `api` instead of `implementation`.

Comment: Do you have additional dependencies to Dagger?

Comment: I just have these dagger dependencies in build.gradle. 
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16"

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for your suggestion. I just add guava api in my build.gradle file. and problem resolved. Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dagger 2 needs Guava so I added Guava library in my `build.gradle` file and problem is resolved.

Add this line in `build.gradle`:

```
 api 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-android'
```